# How do you change css only for safari on mobile

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I'm trying to use a class that will only be active for safari browsers on ios, but unfortunately it also works for firefox on ios.

I've tried these solutions:

```
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm)
{ @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) and (stroke-color:transparent) {
    .safari-only {
       height: 85vh;
   }
}}
```

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .safari-only {
  height: 85vh;
}
```

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
    .safari-only {
        height: 85vh;
    }
}
```

but they all get applied in the firefox browser as well

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{ @media {
    /*
      Safari style
     */
}}
```

Comment: Yes. But I used scss, so it does not work. And when I changed the scss to css it still does not work, because it gives a red line with the message: media query expected